# Shorthand if/else statement inside Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my razor View i have this if/else statement (Its check if there is no Serial number then print Not available otherwise if there is any showing it in Dropdown List):

```
 @{
    var SerialNos = String.Join(", ", Model.SerialNo);
  } 

@if (SerialNos == "")
       {
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label>Serial Number</label>
               <input name="not available" id="notavailable" class="form-control" value="Not available">
                 </div>
         </div>

 }
     else
       {
           <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Serial Number</label>
                 <select class="form-control" id="ddlSerial">
                   <option value="@SerialNos">@SerialNos</option>
                    </select>
            </div>

       </div>

 }
```

And i did if/else in my Script like this , but is there anything i can do to make it shorter in my JavaScript? 
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!
Thanks in advance :)

JavaScript:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

var model = { 

serialnumber: $("#notavailable").val(),
SelectedSerieText: $("#ddlSerial option:selected").text(),

}

  if (model.serialnumber === 'Not available') {

  $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("ProcessRequestRMA", "Account")',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {
        Serienummer: model.serialnumber

               },
                    success: function (status) {

                        if (status) {

                            status.Serienummer = model.serialnumber;

                            console.log("Send");
                        }

                        else {
                            alert("Something Wrong");
                        }

                    },

                    error: function () {
                        console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                    }
                });

            }

      else {


  $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("ProcessRequestRMA", "Account")',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {

        Serienummer: model.SelectedSerieText,


               },
                    success: function (status) {

                        if (status) {

                            status.Serienummer = model.SelectedSerieText;


                            console.log("Send");
                        }

                        else {
                            alert("Something Wrong");
                        }

                    },

                    error: function () {
                        console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                    }
                });


      }


  });

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you creating an `<input ../>` for 'not available'? And why are you creating a `<select>` with only one option? (and there is no reason to repeat all the `<div>` and `<label>` elements

Comment: Messy question IMO. Do you want your if/elses to be shorter in c# or javascript? But from what i gathered, have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: @Joel sorry ma bad , i want for javaScript :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  thanks for pointing in the right direction :) i just changed ma code, but there is i can do to make shorter in ma Javascript ! :)

Comment: You can reduce all this down to a few lines - both the html and javascript :) But you have not answered the question in my first comment (your html makes no sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke :D :D , 1. its because im showing all my data in form and because of dat i used input to show data to user and another reason its because of my desgin and 2. serial number is a list  and i use dropdown list but you right its better i used Html.DropDownList

Comment: 1. - it makes no sense to use an input (and the user could change it so you script would never work correctly anyway) - just add a `<p>Not available</p>` instead - you do not need it for the script. 2. You did not answer the question about why you have only one option. I assume what you really want is an option for each item in your `SerialNo` property? (and then the script can be reduce to about 5 lines)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i understand but input its disabled and user cant change it , i just post related data not all and its beacuse i was trying to find out is there i can do to make shorter if/else in my script . otherwise  i have page which i show different things and when user hit button it should get value and save it into db and so on.

Comment: As I said, the script can be about 5 lines long, but there is no point adding an answer if you just going to come back and say, but xxx (you need to show your real code). And it makes no sense that you are making an ajax call in `$(document).ready()` so its really unclear what the point of this is

Comment: @StephenMuecke alright , not problem i will delete my question and i will ask new question with all code , but before that , if its possbile colud you help me with script , i just try to say if serial number not avalibale just take value from input then save into database (just text i mean ) else if there is serial number take value from DDL then save it into database , but as you i repeated ajax call  one more time in else ,but i think is better way to archive this maybe!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177638/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-7-seconds).